# Security settings in web config for svc services

Tags: c#, wcf

So, I want to get data from a wcf service, http://www.domain/Service.svc. To access, you need a header Authorization: username_value:password_value, in plain text. However, when I try to get data from Service.svc, I receive 400 Bad Request. MY guess is the security part of must be set accordingly. My settings are now:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00">
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName"  />
                </security>
```

Is it OK like this ? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You need to post the client side and server side WCF configuration. Someone will most likely be able to help you then.

Comment: Just refer this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456301/wcf-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-400-bad-request may be this will resolved your query.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="UserName" proxyCredentialType="None" />
</security>
```